# How is path to an executable set if script is in PATH

Tags: shell-script

Suppose I have a `my.sh` script that is placed inside `/var/www` and I added this directory into a `PATH` env variable. Now I can run `./my.sh` anywhere in the system. Inside the script, `$0` is equal to `/var/www/my.sh`. How is it constructed? Is it simply the path in the `PATH` plus the script name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$0` is the name of the running process.

So when you call the script with `./script.sh` the process that will run is `/bin/bash ./script.sh`, then it will `$0` will return `./script.sh` so here it call the script with relative path instead of it's absolute path, but, when you put the script in directory that `PATH` look inside, the call will be with the absolute path, and the return of `$0` will be `/usr/bin/script.sh` because the process is `/bin/bash /usr/bin/script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

`$0` does not care about your `$PATH`, it is a special parameter for Bash.

> $0 expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at
>   shell initialization. If bash is invoked with a file of commands, $0
>   is set to the name of that file. It is often used to display script
>   usage message

Read more about `$0` **[here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$0)**.

Comment: thanks, but can you explain how come it's `/var/www/my.sh` in my case?

Comment: @Maximus Because that is the name of the script, which includes the full path to the script!

Comment: yeah, but if I run it like this `cd /var/www && ./my.sh` it will be only `my.sh`. So in this case it doesn't include the full path

Comment: Yes, it does. The dot `.` shows that you are invoking the script from the same directory you are in. As opposed to if you invoke the script from another place in the system.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
PATH=`/var/www/my.sh`
echo $PATH
```

when you run the script the result will be

/var/www/my.sh